# Travelling within the Schengen zone with a short-time visa EEA family members visa

Tags: visas, schengen, passports, multiple-entry, spouses

I can not find information regarding travel of non-EU nationals who are given a Schengen visas with the remarks stating their status being the family member of an EEA national.

I understand that these visas are issued free of charge and they allow the family members to travel *with* the EU national.

However, here is what I don't understand:

- Is it necessary for the EU spouse to be physically right next to the non-EU spouse at all times?
- What happens if, say, the non-EU spouse goes on a day trip to see a common friend in a different city alone? If this city is in a border country, there might be check on the train or bus, for instance.

I would just like to understand the legality of what happens once the non-EU family member (say, spouse) is in the Schengen area but without being physically right next to the EU citizen from whom s/he derives his or her right to be there in the first place.

Comment: (Speaking from my experience) No. It's not necessary for the EU spouse to accompany the non-EU spouse as long as the visa is valid (not expired). And about your second question crossing the border between the EU countries shouldn't be an issue as long as the non-EU spouse can prove his status of being an EU citizen's family member and the motive of his/her trip.

Comment: @SayedA. You should write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it necessary for the EU spouse to be physically right next to the non-EU spouse at all times?

(Speaking from my experience) No. It's not necessary for the EU spouse to accompany the non-EU spouse as long as the visa is valid (not expired).

> What happens if, say, the non-EU spouse goes on a day trip to see a common friend in a different city alone? If this city is in a border country, there might be check on the train or bus, for instance.

Crossing the borders between the EU countries shouldn't be an issue as long as the non-EU spouse can prove his/her status of being an EU citizen's family member and the motive of his/her trip.